# Ambiguous error in dynamic trait Vec containing polymorphic structs

Tags: rust

I'm a bit confused by the error messaging of rust.
Consider the following code (it doesn't make much sense in this context; the return type of foo could easily be changed to `Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>` which makes much more sense, but in the context if the complete code base this return type does make sense).

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo<'a>(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct<T> {
    type_parameter: T,
}

impl <T: Clone> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> {
    fn foo<'a>(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>> {
        let foos: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>> = Vec::new();
        
        for i in 0..10 {
            let foo = Box::new(self.clone());
            foos.push(foo);
        }
        
        foos
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that the type parameter `T` in `MyStruct<T>` can be outlived by `'a`. When compiling this code the error message I receive is

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:20:23
   |
14 | impl <T: Clone> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> {
   |       -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `T: 'a +`
...
20 |             foos.push(foo);
   |                       ^^^ ...so that the type `MyStruct<T>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

It states that the type parameter `T` can be supplemented with the `'a` lifetime bound. However if i try to do this the compiler states that `'a` is an undefined lifetime bound, and if I declare 'a it says that `'a` is shadowed and I receive the same error as above. Is there any way I can fix this code or have I reached a limitation of rust?

If you'd like to play around with the code, here is a playground https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e490e98f94e98cde3b9db1ac28ee4a5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple solution with minimal lifetime syntax

One fix for this could be to use the `'static` bound on `T` as below. What this indicates is the `impl` for `MyStruct` accepts any type `T` whose fields (if any) hold either only owned data, or references with a static lifetime.

Judging from your use of the `Clone` bound on `T`, I sense that you intend for `MyStruct` to own `T` and where `T` needs to be used by other objects, it will be cloned and subsequently owned by them.

For a good discussion very helpful in understanding the nuances of lifetimes, click [here](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program). An applicable excerpt from this article that talks about the differences between `&'static T` vs. `T: 'static`:

> ... a type with a 'static lifetime is different from a type bounded by a 'static lifetime. The latter can be dynamically allocated at run-time, can be safely and freely mutated, can be dropped, and can live for arbitrary durations.

Another applicable reference on 'static as a trait bound is from [this section in *Rust By Example*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html#trait-bound):

> As a trait bound, it means the type does not contain any non-static references. Eg. the receiver can hold on to the type for as long as they want and it will never become invalid until they drop it.

```
pub trait MyTrait {
    fn get_vec(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct<T> {
    type_parameter: T,
}

impl<T: 'static + Clone> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> {

    fn get_vec(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>> 
    {
        let mut foos: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = Vec::new();
        
        for i in 0..10 {
            foos.push(Box::new(self.clone()));
        }
        foos
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. completely missed it for one reason. I was a bit restrained by using the static lifetime because I (maybe incorrectly) assumed that this would mean that the T type parameter could never be dropped. As stated on the github page
"if T: 'static then T must be valid for the entire program". However when reading your snippet from the same site the contrary seems to be true.

I did get my example to work by using concrete types instead of a type parameter.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7d2847bd1825bd2f444708b67c1bcb1c
does your 'static life time achieve the same thing?

Comment: @CasperLamboo Both our implementations on playground seem to have the same behavior. I added some extra functionality for fun [here's a link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7e8422170c2221c50070ceb47ec64210).  You can run my implementation, then comment it out and uncomment your implementation and see.

Comment: I also called `drop()` on the created instances with no trouble despite the `'static` bound on T.

Comment: @CasperLamboo, I went a step further and compiled both our solutions on the playground page I linked.. and the assembly each produced is nearly identical.

Comment: thanks alot! i understand a bit more about the lifetime system and got my code to work! marked you solution as "accepted"!

Comment: @CasperLamboo, I found some additional info on `'static` as a trait bound that helps clarify it's meaning better and included it above.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of `foo` doesn't really make sense:

```
fn foo<'a>(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>;
```

means that whoever calls the function can choose any lifetime `'a` they want and get a vector of objects with this lifetime. How would that work? Either the returned objects are owned by the struct and their lifetime must be linked to that of the struct, or ownership will be passed to the caller and there is no need for an explicit lifetime.

It is much more likely that the lifetime should be linked to the struct, either with:

```
fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>;
         // ^^ add this
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d3e488419d83ec87faeee0ed98643de)

Or by making the whole trait generic over the lifetime:

```
trait MyTrait<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct<T> {
    type_parameter: T,
}

impl <'a, T: Clone + 'a> MyTrait<'a> for MyStruct<T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>> {
        let mut foos: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>> = Vec::new();
        
        for i in 0..10 {
            let foo = Box::new(self.clone());
            foos.push(foo);
        }
        
        foos
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c7bb6d71c5697c8efac26c66b09435a)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just as clarification as not fully mastered lifetimes yet (if not already apparent). I use the `foo()` function to get mutations of the original struct. After I get these mutations the orignal struct can (must) be dropped, as I make many mutations and mutations of mutations i don't want to keep those in memory. I imagine using `fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>` these orignal structs will be kept alife as long as there are mutations?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you call _"get mutations of the original struct."_ in `fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + 'a>>` the returned value refers to the original struct, so the original _must_ be kept alive for as long as you're using the returned value (the compiler won't do anything specific to keep it alive, but it will check that _you_ do).

Comment: OTOH, if `foo` should consume `self` because it gets replaced by something else, then the prototype should reflect this: `fn foo (self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` (no lifetime and no references).

Comment: `foo` returns a vec of cloned values, why does the original struct need to be kept alive if I'll only use the cloned values?

Comment: Because that's what your function prototype says ;) It sounds like for you the correct prototype is `fn foo (&self) -> Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` but you will need to specify that `T: 'static` to guarantee that the cloned values don't contain a reference linked to the lifetime of `self` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f4e6885468bf17f0269d41faf52dd5e))

Comment: this is the same thing that @todd said right? Thanks! i was a bit confused as I thought static meant that the variable will be kept alive during the whole execution of the program. But this is not the case right?